# LaTeX Font Shape Unavailable and Substitution

Tags: fonts, texstudio, texshop

So I got a Beamer template from my professor, and I ran his code on TeXStudio (he ran his code on TeXShop). I got this:

`` Font shape `TU/lmss/m/sc' in size <6> not available(Font) Font shape `TU/lmr/m/sc' tried instead ``

Is there a way to make sure that `TU/lmss/m/sc` is available?

Comment: Please show the command that gives rise to this message.

Comment: texstudio and texshop are both just editors neither is responsible for typesetting the document or raising the error that you show. When asking about errors or warnings please always show a small document that produces the warning.